# How to describe or ask about empty seat on a train ir

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

I stuck while describing the following situations.
on bus or a train can I say  'This seat is empty/vacant?  Secondly, Can I say 'This house is vacant and is ready to let on rent? Thirdly how can I use words such as empty ,free,vacant,unoccupied to describe seat 'room or house?

Comment: Hello, I looked at your profile and noticed that you have never marked an answer as "accepted" (i.e., you haven't accepted answers to any of your 33 questions). While you are not required to select an answer as the "accepted" one, it is a good thing to do so. It rewards people who take the time to write answers for you. :)

Comment: I appreciate your feedback . I hv been benefitted a lot by the assistance extended by you all but I was unaware of marking the answers as "accepted" My appologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Vacant" is an adjective that can be used for seats, rooms and houses.

So you can "This seat/room/house/ is vacant"

You can also use "empty or unoccupied" and be understood.

For seats we are also likely to say "not taken".  It is obvious that the seat is empty (nobody there) but an empty seat could be taken by someone who is coming back. So "taken" is a useful word to describe a seat on a train.

In context "empty" could also mean "completely empty of furniture"  We always understand sentences in context.